# How to use Javascript for loop to create buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I defined a several buttons using C# in behind. How can I do this in Javascript in front?

```
for (int r = 0; r < data.Count; r++)
{
    var buttonField = new ButtonField
    {
        ButtonType = ButtonType.Button,
        Text = "Button",
        CommandName = "Display",                
    };
    break;
}
```

Comment: 1) Start by learning some basic JavaScript. 2) Write some code and see if it works 3) If it doesn't work post a question here with the code you've written and we'll do our best to help you. 4) Read [the help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to see how to ask a good question. Stackoverflow is not a coding service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help

```
var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i=0; i < 5 ; i++){
     var elem = document.createElement('input');
     elem.type = 'button';
     elem.value = 'button';
     docFrag.appendChild(elem);
}
document.body.appendChild(docFrag);
```

Comment: This is a really inefficient way of doing this. You should create a docfragment, add all the buttons to that and then attach the fragment to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks Mahesh, it works perfect!

Comment: @Tong, then you should mark this answer correct instead.

Comment: Upvoted as this was updated first and is the one I'd personally go with.

Comment: Side note: defining `i` outside of the loop is pointless, most people are conditioned to see this defined in the for() statement. Also you store `document` in `doc` but then immediately do not use it.

Answer (score 2):

For a pure javascript approach, without using jquery,

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var buttonsWanted = 10;
  var doc = document;
  var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

  for(var x = 0; x < buttonsWanted; x++){
    var button = doc.createElement('button');
    button.setAttribute('text', 'yourtext');
    docFrag.appendChild(button);
  }

  doc.getElementById('container').appendChild(docFrag);
});
```

This code will create 10 buttons, as defined by buttons wanted. It will append them to an element with an ID of 'container'. Make sure you change this to your actual element.

### EDIT:

Updated to reflect @Andy's suggestion of using a document fragment to improve performance.

Comment: This is a really inefficient way of doing this. You should create a docfragment, add all the buttons to that and then attach the fragment to the DOM.

Comment: @andy Ah, I hadn't thought of that, not sure how to create docfragments. Thanks for the tip though, will look in to that!

Comment: [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)

Comment: @Andy - you seem like you'd know. Is it worth deleting an answer like this if it is likely to do more harm than good?

Comment: Up to you. I'd probably update the answer. I don't get things right the first time either. :) See Mahesh Durairaj's answer on how he implemented the docfrag after I pointed it out.

Comment: @Andy document fragment is good for lots of buttons to be more efficient, but for a calculator with approx 15 buttons probably not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery to manipulate the Website Content.

Imagine you wrote a website with the div container. Just use the jQuery.html Method to directly modify the content of this div.

HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var html = "";
for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
    html += "<button>Ein Button</button>";
$("#container").html(html);
});
```

[Try this Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s9amdek6/)

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
          for (i=0; i < 5 ; i++){
                var element = document.createElement("input");
                //Assign different attributes to the element. 
                element.setAttribute("type", type);
                element.setAttribute("value", type);
                element.setAttribute("name", type);
                //element.setAttribute("onclick", ); If you wish to add click event

                //Append the element in page (in span).  
               document.body.appendChild(element);
          }
```

Answer (score -1):

This will do:

```
var d = document.createDocumentFragment();
for(var i = 1; i <= 10 ; i++){
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    element.type  = "button";
    element.value = 'button' + i;
    d.appendChild(element);
}
document.body.appendChild(d);
```

Comment: Again, this is a really inefficient way of doing this. You should create a docfragment, add all the buttons to that and then attach the fragment to the DOM.

Comment: Tong, out of all the answers you could have chosen, this one wasn't the best. See my comment.

Comment: Thanks Paul, it works perfect!

Comment: @Andy Where is your solution? Thanks. I also need to write onclick function into this loop. However, there will be two functions trigger by this button. How can I do that?

Comment: @Tong, I didn't write one. I'm pointing out this isn't an efficient solution whereas the other answers are. Second, this is still basic JS. Go and read a couple of tutorials.

Comment: Updated my answer. Thanks